# Big performance difference between WinForms and Wpf examples

Tags: cefsharp

I notice a very important performance difference (in FPS) between the CefSharp.WinForms.Example and CefSharp.Wpf.Example when using http://www.vsynctester.com

When turning off VSync in my video card control panel and in the settings in CefExample Init()

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "0");
```

For CefSharp.WinForms.Example I get around **500 FPS** (steady)
For CefSharp.Wpf.Example I barely get **30 FPS**

I understand that Wpf uses offscreen rendering, but what explains the big performance difference for the same web page?

I'm using a MacBook Pro with Win 8.1 with NVidia GT 750M Graphics.
CefSharp version is 8755a9496ffbd5f21bc6ef062bce687a22d83938 (March 1st 2015) and Cef version 3.2171.1979

Comment: How did you find out that "Wpf uses offscreen rendering"?

Answer (score 2):

> The maximum rate in frames per second (fps) that CefRenderHandler::OnPaint will be called for a windowless browser. The actual fps may be lower if the browser cannot generate frames at the requested rate. The minimum value is 1 and the maximum value is 60 (default 30).

Direct quote from the CEF documentation see http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/_cef_browser_settings_t.html#windowless_frame_rate

The entire process is more CPU bound that it is GPU bound. The slow part is the bitmap buffer is copied in memory, before it's displayed. `CEF` also supports `DirtyRects` which is currently not implemented, so even a small graphical change forces a complete screen redraw.

When the upstream `CEF` issue 1006 is resolved we can then look at making some more improvements.
https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1006&q=label%3AOSR

Comment: Did the performance issues with the WPF release get improved, or is the HwndHost release still the one that must be used for better performance?